# What UI elements can be changed in The Division 2

Tags: the-division-2

From the Division 2 graphical settings menu it appears that the radar and some Conflict-related UI elements (eg: scoreboard) can be moved, scaled, and saved.

Tooltips, tutorials, pickups and notifications don't appear to be movable from the UI settings menu. Is there a way to adjust these elements, or a list of what UI elements can be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the persistent items like Mini Map, XP, Group Info and the PvP score can be moved, scale and saved.

But there are multiple open threads and suggestions to their R&D to improve the UI and make it more customizable in the near future